# “It was great seeing you.” “You too.”  Why not “Me too”?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, conversation

In response to "It was great seeing you," why do people say "you, too" instead of "me, too?"

Answer (score 12):

When someone says "it was great seeing you," people often respond, "it was great seeing you too." This can be shortened to just "you too," but the meaning is the same.

Comment: likewise, would be clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer 'you too' is a shortened form of 'It was great seeing you too.' The alternative you are suggesting isn't grammatically correct. In another example: 'I had a great time tonight' the response is 'Me too', not 'You too'.

Comment: Quite so. *"Me too"* might be a bit more natural if someone said *"I've enjoyed being with you today"*, but even there it's a bit odd because of the switching subject/object. Personally, I'd feel happier replying with *"Likewise"*.

Comment: The full explanation would help this answer: Replying "Me too" would have to correspond to "It was great seeing me too" which actually *is* grammatical, but very narcissistic and not what was intended.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rhetorical device known as [ellipsis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/E/ellipsis.htm):

> **ellipsis** |iˈlipsis|
>   *noun* ( pl. ellipses |-sēz| )
>   the omission from speech or writing of a word or words that are superfluous or able to be understood from contextual clues.

Now, it may seem a little grand to call an abbreviated greeting a form of rhetoric, but that's what it is.